# Having conditional multiple filters in Morphia query for Mongo database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, morphia, mongo-java-driver, database

**Environment : MongoDb 3.2, Morphia 1.1.0**

So lets say i am having a collection of Employees and Employee entity has several fields. I need to do something like apply multiple filters **(conditional)** and return a batch of 10 records per request.

pesudocode as below.

```
@Entity("Employee")
Employee{
 String firstname,
 String lastName,
 int salary,
 int deptCode,
 String nationality
}
```

and in my `EmployeeFilterRequest`i carry the request parameter to the dao

```
EmployeeFilterRequest{
 int salaryLessThen
 int deptCode,
 String nationality..
}
```

Pseudoclass

```
class EmployeeDao{

public List<Employee> returnList;

public getFilteredResponse(EmployeeFilterRequest request){
   DataStore ds = getTheDatastore();

   Query<Employee> query = ds.createQuery(Emploee.class).disableValidation();

   //conditional request #1
   if(request.filterBySalary){
     query.filter("salary >", request.salary);
   }

   //conditional request #2
   if(request.filterBydeptCode){
     query.filter("deptCode ==", request.deptCode);
   }

   //conditional request #3
   if(request.filterByNationality){
     query.filter("nationality ==", request.nationality);
   }

   returnList = query.batchSize(10).asList();

/******* **THIS IS RETURNING ME ALL THE RECORDS IN THE COLLECTION, EXPECTED ONLY 10** *****/
 }
}
```

SO as explained above in the code.. i want to perform conditional filtering on multiple fields. and even if batchSize is present as 10, i am getting complete records in the collection.

how to resolve this ???

Regards
Punith

Comment: I think you are mistaking `.batchSize()` for `.limit()`, which are two different things.

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven !! this solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blakes is right.  You want to use `limit()` rather than `batchSize()`.  The batch size only affects how many documents each trip to the server comes back with.  This can be useful when pulling over a lot of really large documents but it doesn't affect the total number of documents fetched by the query.

As a side note, you should be careful using `asList()` as it will create objects out of every document returned by the query and could exhaust your VM's heap.  Using `fetch()` will let you incrementally hydrate documents as you need each one.  You might actually need them all as a List and with a size of 10 this is probably fine.  It's just something to keep in mind as you work with other queries.